# Can't send email (gmail) via python

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

I have a code which was working like a half year ago. It basiclly sends email.

```
import smtplib
import socket

gmail_user="SENDERMAIL"
gmail_password="SENDERPASS"
to = 'SENDTOTHIS'

email_text = "ADSADSADSA"

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.starttls()
    server.sendmail(gmail_user, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    #I was using this code below and it was working. I tried above code but it also did not work.
    #server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
    #server.ehlo()
    #server.starttls()
    #server.ehlo()
    #server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    #server.sendmail(gmail_user, to, email_text)
    #server.close()
    print("Done")
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception)
```

Here's exception

> (534, b'5.7.14
>
> 5.7.14 KL7_2qGSLW9IBjP8dKKgP67bEgyKNc5ls76dnVDZcUlVQjJUQb0JX9BIVi_Agb84vKNOKB
>
> 5.7.14 fshB0ngZ_Tn8ocDpDHKavRKXmluVjHo5YM7ADKENtWn4aVTxyvaBlbXRGpA1EBh91bdV-o
>
> 5.7.14 pwiAWUHXKmRQEuSNSiFcv68DP4a7ghIu9YKnTyqtUEhGd4HgKtxa4Jz0mhSQDjD13UQWYB
>
> 5.7.14 -YEL5Sd2h5YxN8kkSAsK-J_hXMbpy7wNyeCov8lq1Aa3spZzgo> Please log in via
>
> 5.7.14 your web browser and then try again.
>
> 5.7.14  Learn more at
>
> 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f132-v6sm3660398wme.24 - gsmtp')

I did try to

- logined gmail
- add device to trusted devices
- turned on IMAP via gmail
- [let less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)
- tried this:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=636711453029417344-336837064&rd=2#cantsignin

Comment: I had the same issue a few nights ago. Double check to make sure less secure apps didn't turn back off. It did for me.

Comment: Have you seen the link they give you?
They say use full email address, which is different than the user, what happens if you use full email address?

Comment: @ltd9938 I did check again and I received email about this.

Comment: @E.Serra Actually I do use full email address

Answer (score 0):

There are to many ways to solve this problem. I hope this code helps. 
The only thing you need to do is filling the required variables.

```
    import socket
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    # 
    message = "Your message" # Type your message
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    password = "********" # Type your password 
    msg['From'] = "from@gmail.com" # Type your own gmail address 
    msg['To'] = "To@gmail.com" # Type your friend's mail address  
    msg['Subject'] = "title" # Type the subject of your message 
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(msg['From'], password)
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Please change the "print(exception)" to print(str(exception)) so We can see the error string message

Comment: Changed output in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look

Comment: I think your problem will be solved with this : https://medium.com/@samarsrivastava44/send-mail-from-your-gmail-account-with-python-and-cmd-shell-without-using-browser-110c3c188176

Comment: Would you do me a favour and send the code that you solved your problem with?

Comment: Actually code is same. I just changed password with app token as link suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I can also advise to use a simpler library (a wrapper on top of smtplib, to make sure there are no other factors involved).... like [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) (disclaimer: I'm the developer).

Try to see if this works:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP("username", "password")
yag.send(subject="hi")
```

Comment: @E141 Maybe one of the exceptions there could help?